# Reusing CIDetector in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cidetector

I am writing an iOS app using swift and need to analyse many photos in parallel. 
In order to do that, I plan to use a single CIDetector instance (as recommended by Apple).

 
Is it safe to use the same instance of CIDetector in **different threads**?
Tried to find a documentation about it but had no luck.

Comment: Docs say "This class can maintain many state variables that can impact performance. So for best performance, reuse CIDetector instances instead of creating new ones" - instanceS - why do you say they recommend only one instance?

Comment: Probably I was not clear enough, I meant that they recommend reusing the CIDetector. I am sure it is possible to create several instances, but for simplicity I would prefer using only one instance.